# Video transferred over GRPC plays slow

Tags: python, video, video-streaming, grpc

I've written the following code to transfer a video over GRPC. Im using client-side streaming. The client sends the video in frames over the stream. Each frame is converted to bytes datatype and is transferred.

But my video is playing slower than the actual speed. How do I ensure that the video plays at the actual speed?

**imageTest.proto file**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";


// The greeting service definition.
service ImageTest {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc Analyse (stream MsgRequest) returns (MsgReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the image.
message MsgRequest {
  bytes img = 1;
}

// The response message containing the reply
message MsgReply {
  int32 reply = 1;
}
```

**imageTest_server.py**

```
class Greeter(imageTest_pb2_grpc.ImageTestServicer):

def Analyse(self, request_iterator, context):
  for req in request_iterator:
      frame = np.array(list(req.img))
      frame = frame.reshape( (576,704) )
      frame = np.array(frame, dtype = np.uint8 )

      cv2.imshow('Processed Image', frame)
      cv2.waitKey(1)


return imageTest_pb2.MsgReply(reply = cnt )


def serve():
  server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
  imageTest_pb2_grpc.add_ImageTestServicer_to_server(Greeter(),     server)
  server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
  server.start()
  try:
    while True:
    time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
  server.stop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  serve()
```

**imageTest_client.py**

```
def run():
   channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
   stub = imageTest_pb2_grpc.ImageTestStub(channel)
   response = stub.Analyse( generateRequests() )

def generateRequests():
    videogen = skvideo.io.vreader(URL)
    for frame in videogen:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor( frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY )
        frame = bytes(frame)     
        yield imageTest_pb2.MsgRequest(img= frame)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

Comment: How much end-to-end system profiling have you done? Are you able to diagnose where your bottlenecks are?